# Replacing all zero values with first occurring non-zero value in the numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array that looks like:

```
[0,0,0,1,2,0,0,3,0,0,9]
```

I want to transform this array into:

```
[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,9,9,9]
```

As you could see all zero values have been replaced with the next non zero value. Is there a way with `numpy` where I could do this?

Comment: With `a` as the input array, use `fill_zeros_with_last(a[::-1])[::-1]` from the linked dup.